# IllegalStateException on ScrollView Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview

I have a layout file that has child views wrapped in a `LinearLayout` wrapped in a `ScrollView`. To summarize that layout file:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/scrollViewChildLayout">
        ... lots of text and image views ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm using a `SherlockListFragment` in conjunction with another `SherlockFragment` to create something similar to the Headlines+Articles fragment detailed by Google [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) My headlines fragment is using a `ListView`, while my Articles fragment is using the `ScrollView` layout described above.

Currently, I'm coding for phones, so I'm using the `FrameLayout` replacement technique when working with the fragments. I can get to my "Articles" fragment just fine, but when I press back, the following error occurs. This seems to be occurring because of the `ScrollView` because swapping this out with just a regular LinearLayout works fine. Does anyone know why this issue is being caused and can point to the correct way to address it?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3339)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3155)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131)
        at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:764)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1493)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:477)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:174)
        at com.tomra.recycle.AccountActivity.onBackPressed(AccountActivity.java:129)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2145)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2375)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:122)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: with seeing your implemented code it is difficult to guess the root cause..

Comment: I'm using the same implementation as the Flexible UI article that I linked to. The only difference is that my Articles fragment uses the layout file I described earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Strange behavior, but changing the layout inflation in the onCreateView solved this issue. Seems like the view is retaining the previous view and trying to inflate it. Changing the savedInstanceState override to `false` fixed. Updated the onCreateView as below.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "onCreateView");

        mInflater = inflater;

        // rootView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ach_list_layout, container, savedInstanceState);
        rootView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ach_list_layout, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
```